# I can't quite understand how this while loop works

Tags: python, while-loop

This code essentially prompts the user to enter their name and say hello to them and if no value is entered by the user is keeps on prompting for their name .

```
name = None

while not name:

    name = input('what is your name ? ')

print('hello '+name)
```

How does this while loop work , Because as I can understand this while loop checks if the  variable name is not null then the condition for the loop is true and keeps on going but how is it not working like that .

Comment: Strings have a "truthiness". Empty strings are `False`, all others are `True`. This code is accepting any user input except just hitting the return key.

Comment: the `input` command is blocking, so the while loop is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If the user does not input anything, `input` returns `''` (empty string) and `not ''` is `True`, so in that case the loop would continue.

The `print` would do well to use an f-string.

```
print(f"hello {name}")
```

Comment: I do understand that thanks for clarifying , but what I don't get is how when the user enters a value the condition for the while loop is false and we get out of the loop , Thanks in advance.

Comment: `not 'foo'` => `False`